# String not updating

Tags: php, session, pdo

I am using MVC and also PDO. I am trying to update a string depending on whether the session is empty or not, so in my index.phtml I have:

```
<?php if (!empty($_SESSION)) :?>
    <p>
        Welcome back, <a href="logout.php"><?php echo $_SESSION["info"]["users_name"];?></a>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(empty($_SESSION)) : ?>
    <p>
        Hello, would you like to <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">sign in</a>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So if the session is empty then show "Hello would you like to sign in" by clicking sign in, it opens the login modal, and if the session is not empty it shows "Welcome back user" and changes the link to logout.php. The only problem I am having is that it doesn't update the string, when the session is not empty. My login modal works perfectly as if the user types in the wrong password it redirects to index.php and says "Wrong pass", however if the user logs in it redirects to index.php but does not update the string.

If it helps this is my index.php:

```
<?php
require("Models/UserData.php");
$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'Login';

if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $userVeri = new UserData();

    $result = $userVeri->login($_POST["email"],$_POST["password"]);

    if (!empty($result)) {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION["info"] = $result;

        header("Location: index.php");

        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Wrong pass";
    }
}

 // Then verify it


 require("Views/index.phtml");
```

In my index.phtml I have text inputs named "email" and "password" so everythings linking perfectly, it just seems that the string is not updating. Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
session_start();
```

to the top of your file, it has to be the first thing executing in your file.

The session must be running before any writing or reading is done with the session variables or any output is written to the browser. What matters is that you don't want sessions to exist depending on whether they have a proper key with a proper value or not; if you may at some point in your code require a session value from a session key then you always want to have an ongoing session, i.e. by calling it from the beginning, so that it's available when you need it, without you having to understand what's breaking it.

It is also important to know that calling `session_start()` in `a.php` will not make the session live in `b.php` unless `session_start()` is called in `b.php` aswell. Or, if you redirect `a.php` to `a.php` (refresh) then the session will not live unless you have `session_start()` at the beginning of the file, so using if statements to determine whether a session should be ongoing is not going to work, values will be lost in between, if it works to begin with.