# PHP login not remembered/detected by redirect page

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I'm building a user login system with PHP and MySQL using this tutorial.
http://m.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL.

login_process.php

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    } else {
        echo 'Oops, we are unable to log you in. Please <a href="../login.php" target="_self">try again</a> or <a href="../register.php" target="_self">register</a> first.';
        // Login failed 
      //  header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

protected_page.php

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Protected Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
            <p>
                This is an example protected page.  To access this page, users
                must be logged in.  At some stage, we'll also check the role of
                the user, so pages will be able to determine the type of user
                authorised to access the page.
            </p>
            <p>Return to <a href="login.php">login page</a></p>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="login.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the protected_page.php returns in the "You are not authorized to access this page" state. That means login.php accepts the credentials, but the login isn't recorded after redirecting to the next page. Any possible solutions?

edit:

login()

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

login_check()

```
function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['username'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                      FROM members 
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';   // As functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

psl-config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * These are the database login details
 */  
define("HOST", "[host_ip]:[port]");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "[db uname]");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "[db pass]");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "[db name]");    // The database name.

define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", TRUE);    
?>
```

sec_session_start()

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Comment: What does `login()` do?  What does `login_check()` do?  When you debug into those functions, where does one (or both) of them fail in some way?

Comment: I'm unable to see how you are storing you login session. Reading your code what is $mysqli? More code needed!

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I added login() and login_check() to the OP. I'm not sure how to debug them, but I basically took them straight from the tutorial in the link

Comment: In the login check, echoes something else in all cases instead to return, to see exactly what happens, what executed. Then you can figure out why. also `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see, is the right values in it.

Comment: @lolka_bolka the first if() statement in login_check seems to be failing

Comment: So your problem will be in your login function. Let's go, and add some strings in ALL condition to echo, so you will see, where it fails. And anyway, what is this? `$_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);` If i am using chrome instead firefox, then I can't login? :)

Comment: I added echo functions to all conditions, but it only keeps telling me about the first if() statement in login_check

Also, I am not sure what `$_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);` does, can I just delete the line?

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
sec_session_start();
```

to the top of the page, actually, it has to be on top of *every* page you use.

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402196/string-not-updating/27402600#27402600) of mine.

Comment: @Tommie Okay, but why are you not doing it then? It has to be _above_ the includes and requires.

Comment: Ah, that I was not aware of. Will try now!

Comment: Tried, and get Internal Server Errors now.. Makes sense too, because how should it read the function when functions.php is not included yet?

Comment: Defining the sec_session_start is probably okay but everything else should be added after calling sec_session_start.

Comment: I've tried moving it around, but it only seems to work when positioned as showed in protected_page.php in my original question

Comment: I have now put session_start(); on the very top of the page, and that works. The issue seems to be in the sec_session_start function itself!

Answer (score 0):

> in login_process.php
>       change

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['p'])) { }
```

> in login_check()
>       change

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) &&
    isset($_SESSION['username']) &&
    isset($_SESSION['login_string'])) { }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jivani. I tried this, but sadly it has no effect