# Simple password check using $_SESSION. Cant check SESSION['pass'] using if

Tags: php, session, post, if-statement

I cant for the life of me get this to work, I have hacked the code back to the bare minimum, obviously the `}else{` at the end would contact a simple form which submits through `$_POST`.

I know this is not best practice to store authentication in a session but this is for stand alone page with a calender so 'top security' is not a priority.

Here is the code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();


if($_SESSION['passw'] === "word") {

echo 'password checked ok<br>';

}elseif($_POST['password'] === "word"){

$_SESSION['passw'] = "word";
unset($_POST);
}else{

$_POST['password'] = "word";
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}


?>
```

Any thoughts much much appreciated:-)

Comment: Don't bother the if statement, always use `session_start();` at the beginning of your file, it's mandatory. The session can't possibly exist, it doesn't exist in your new file just because you started it in an old file, you need to keep the session alive in every single file. [Similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402196/string-not-updating/27402600#27402600) just a few hours ago.

Comment: you need to initiate `session_start();` regardless of whether the session has been started or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `$_SESSION` is set even if you haven't started the session yet.

So since you aren't starting the session, it can't be saved to.

Just use `session_start()` by itself, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that's how i started, i only started using isset to see if it was setting the session that was causing the problem